# how to override alignment from within nested element - HTML

Tags: html, css

How can I align paragraph "I wish to be on right." from right? The following code fails to do that.

```
<head>
<style> 
.LeftA {
align: left; 
} 
</style> 
</head>
<body>
<div class="LeftA">

<p>I am on left.</p>

<p style="align: right;">I wish to be on right.</p>

</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for text you can use "text-align" and for blocks "float".
You don´t have to use "text-align: left", because it is the default value.

```css
.text-right {
  text-align: right;
}
.right {
  float: right;
}
.box {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
}
.box.right {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<p>I am on left.</p>
<p class="text-right">I wish to be on right.</p>


<div class=" box "></div>
<div class="box right "></div>
```

Comment: I can only change code inside the `div` block; because the rest is set by the program.